# issue on yahoo finance api for currency converter

Tags: java, android, eclipse, yahoo-finance

I am following this tutorial to build a currency converter by referring Yahoo Finance: 
http://www.firstamong.com/building-android-currency-converter/

while download the codes, the apps run perfectly.
But when I copy those codes to my own project. It is not working. The apps will be closed after I hit on the convert button.

I wish to ask, is it the YQL api is only allow for one project?
What if I wish to apply another api key? which part of my coding should be modified?
I am on my way to learn this currency converter. Hope can get helps.

```
public class CurrencyActivity extends Activity {
public int to;
public int from;
public String [] val;
public String s;
public Handler handler;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_currency);
    Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    Spinner s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.name, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
    val  = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.value);
    s1.setAdapter(adapter);
    s2.setAdapter(adapter);
    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new spinOne(1));
    s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new spinOne(2));
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            if(from == to)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid", 4000).show();
            }
            else
            {
                  try {
                     s = getJson("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22"+val[from]+val[to]+"%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=");
                    JSONObject jObj;
                    jObj = new JSONObject(s);
                    String exResult = jObj.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results").getJSONObject("rate").getString("Rate");
                    t.setText(exResult);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }   

    });
     TextView credit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
     credit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("http://finance.yahoo.com"));
            startActivity(i);
        }

     });
}
public String getJson(String url)throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream content = entity.getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
    String con;
    while ((con = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                build.append(con);
            }
    return build.toString();
}
private class spinOne implements OnItemSelectedListener
{
    int ide;
    spinOne(int i)
    {
        ide =i;
    }
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int index, long id) {
        if(ide == 1)
            from = index;
        else if(ide == 2)
            to = index;

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
}
```

**UPDATED -- log**

```
03-05 00:19:08.531: D/dalvikvm(4432): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 398K, 17% free 10431K/12504K, paused 15ms, total 16ms
03-05 00:19:08.576: D/dalvikvm(4432): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 278K, 17% free 10926K/13076K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
03-05 00:19:08.646: D/dalvikvm(4432): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 466K, 17% free 11765K/14080K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
03-05 00:19:08.686: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:08.691: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:08.691: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:08.696: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:08.696: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:08.696: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:08.696: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:08.696: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:08.696: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:08.701: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:08.746: D/libEGL(4432): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
03-05 00:19:08.746: D/libEGL(4432): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
03-05 00:19:08.751: D/libEGL(4432): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
03-05 00:19:08.756: E/(4432): Device driver API match
03-05 00:19:08.756: E/(4432): Device driver API version: 23
03-05 00:19:08.756: E/(4432): User space API version: 23 
03-05 00:19:08.756: E/(4432): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Fri Nov 29     14:18:37 KST 2013 
03-05 00:19:08.846: D/OpenGLRenderer(4432): Enabling debug mode 0
03-05 00:19:08.871: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:08.871: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:08.871: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:08.871: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:08.871: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:08.871: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:08.871: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:08.876: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:08.876: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:08.876: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:11.636: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:11.636: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:11.641: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:11.641: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:11.641: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:11.646: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:11.646: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:11.646: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:11.711: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:11.711: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:11.711: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:11.716: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:11.716: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:11.716: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:11.716: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:11.716: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:11.716: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:13.301: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:13.301: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:13.301: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:13.301: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:13.301: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:13.301: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:13.301: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:13.301: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:13.316: D/AbsListView(4432): Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-05 00:19:13.411: D/AbsListView(4432): unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-05 00:19:13.411: D/AbsListView(4432): unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-05 00:19:13.411: D/AbsListView(4432): unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-05 00:19:13.411: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:13.411: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:13.411: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:13.416: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:13.416: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:13.416: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:13.416: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:13.416: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:13.436: D/AbsListView(4432): unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-05 00:19:14.406: D/AbsListView(4432): onDetachedFromWindow
03-05 00:19:14.441: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:14.451: D/TextLayoutCache(4432): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
03-05 00:19:14.461: E/ViewRootImpl(4432): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
03-05 00:19:15.026: D/AbsListView(4432): Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-05 00:19:15.131: D/AbsListView(4432): unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-05 00:19:15.131: D/AbsListView(4432): unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-05 00:19:15.136: D/AbsListView(4432): unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-05 00:19:15.156: D/AbsListView(4432): unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-05 00:19:15.741: D/AbsListView(4432): onDetachedFromWindow
03-05 00:19:15.761: W/InputEventReceiver(4432): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
03-05 00:19:15.771: E/ViewRootImpl(4432): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
03-05 00:19:16.861: D/AndroidRuntime(4432): Shutting down VM
03-05 00:19:16.861: W/dalvikvm(4432): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41cf5700)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1144)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at com.example.test.CurrencyActivity.getJson(CurrencyActivity.java:101)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at com.example.test.CurrencyActivity$1.onClick(CurrencyActivity.java:64)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
03-05 00:19:16.871: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You need to provide us the Logcat so we can see why the app is crashing!

Comment: hi @mario, i have updated my question. please take a look. thanks

Comment: `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` You need to move your `getJson()` to a thread like AsyncTask or Service

Comment: Hi, @mario , I would like to know how to move the getJson() to AsyncTask.. is it move the whole fragment of codes inside the 'try'?

Comment: Read up on AsyncTask, look at tutorials online! [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)